# Best way to communicate with Java server from HTML5 using SSL

Tags: java, html, ssl

Hows it going, 
as you can see by the title, I am trying to communicate with my Java Server from a HTML5 Client. Because I will be sending sensitive data, what is the best way to send data, and recieve it back from the server through HTML and Java whilst keeping it secure using SSL. I am using github pages for now, but I am planning on getting a dedicated host pretty soon, possibly hosting it myself. This is for a messaging system I am working on that will be cross-platform, eg iOS, Android and a web browser. For iOS and Android, I am using SSLServerSockets, which work fine, but i have not come upon a solution for my web client. Any thoughts on this? I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: I'd use Https which basically is Http + SSL.

Comment: @Thomas I have been considering this, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: How exactly, would you suggest achieving this?

Comment: Just get a certificate (you'd need to buy one if you don't want the browsers to complain about a potentially unsecure certificate) and configure your webserver accordingly (how you do that depends on the webserver). It's  a standard protocol so the net should be full of detailed tutorials - and since Browsers, Android, iOS etc. support it you don't need any specific implementation. Quite the opposite: you can develop your application without taking any special measures (except maybe some cookie/session handling) and let the web or application server handle secure communications.